# How to achieve this result (add half screen modal view but with both views functional)

Tags: ios, swift, view

i'm not quite sure how to achieve next step in my iOS app built in Swift and searching for it gave me some solutions but with some disadvantages, so maybe someone can suggest what would be the best and most up to date solution here.

Here is how the app supposed to work:

Main screen filled with cells from Collection View. After selecting the cell some buttons will show up on the cell (like edit, delete and some others). That's what i managed to do so far.

What i want is to do now is to add additional calendar view on half of the screen which will also show up after selecting that cell. Both views have to be functional, cell buttons clickable and calendar view buttons clickable too. What i would also like to achieve is changing selected cell through calendar view and moving cells rows up if necessary to always keep the selected cell in the view

How it looks like and supposed to look like
[image]

How should i approach it? Make another View Controller? Will those buttons from first view work though? Or just add subview hidden till cell is selected? How to move cell rows to keep selected one in top of the screen then?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new UIView and of course a ViewController for it. if you prefer to add it's constraints programmatically you could use

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    //Add your view constraints

    ])
```

or of course you could use the Storyboard, make sure to set the height of the UIView either to be a fraction of the superview or a constant depending on your preference. 
Then present and dismiss the preview accordingly

```
    present(UIViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you could add animations if you would like to the completion handler

Comment: Thanks, so I made a container view as child vc displayed after clicking the button and everything works fine but when i dismiss it cells from main view go slightly up hiding partially under navigation bar. Any quick solution for that?

Comment: I think the issue might be in your constraints after you remove the view